# Mongoose model is not returning data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to setup a model but there is no data rendering on the page (using a handlebars view engine).

I have the following in an app.js file:

```
// Mongoose setup
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nickinumbers');
```

And then this is the model I setup for the data I need returned this is ina nickinumbers.js file:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var NickiNumberSchema = new Schema({
   number: {type: 'String', required: true},
   firstName: {type: 'String'}
 });
 var NickiNumber = mongoose.model('Nickinumber', NickiNumberSchema);
 module.exports = NickiNumber;
```

Finally, my index.js router file contains:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var NickiNumber = require('../models/nickinumbers');
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        NickiNumber.find(function(err, nums) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            res.render('index', {title: 'Users', nums: nums});
    }); 
});



module.exports = router;
```

I'm not seeing any errors on the server or in the console and I can't figure out why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In **find** function **first parameters is query condition** then apply **callback**.

so you should use query condition `{}` to get all records or can apply your query. so should use `NickiNumber.find({}, function(...`

Query should be like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var NickiNumber = require('../models/nickinumbers');
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        NickiNumber.find({}, function(err, nums) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            res.render('index', {title: 'Users', nums: nums});
    }); 
});

module.exports = router;
```